# Comparing a string with a character in C++

Tags: c++

Hey Guys, I'm trying to write a program that calculates the GPA of a student. For some reason the compiler is giving me an error when comparing two strings, but I cant seem to find the reasons for it. Below you will find the piece of code that is giving me error. I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure it out.

ERROR: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int strncmp(const char*, const char*, size_t)’

```
double StudentInfo::getGPA() {
double temp = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < totalCourses; i++) { 
    if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade(), "A") == 0) //Gets string "grade", and compares it to "A".
        temp = temp + 4;
    if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade(),"A-", 2) == 0)
        temp = temp + 3.7;
    if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade(), "B+", 2) == 0)
        temp = temp + 3.3;
    if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade(), "B") == 0)
        temp = temp + 3;
    if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade(), "B-", 2) == 0)
        temp = temp + 2.7;
    if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade(), "C+", 2) == 0)
        temp = temp + 2.3;
    if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade(), "C") == 0)
        temp = temp + 2;
    if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade(), "C-") == 0)
        temp = temp + 1.7;
    if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade(), "D+") == 0)
        temp = temp + 1.3;
    if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade(), "D") == 0)
        temp = temp + 1;
    else
        temp = temp + 0;
}
GPA = temp/totalCourses;
return GPA;}
```

Comment: Not sure it's your error, but most of your strncmp lines are missing the third argument (giving the length to compare)

Answer (score 9):

You do not have to use `strncmp` for this. If you want string equality you can write code like this:

```
if (Courses[i].getGrade() == "A")
 // ...
```

**edit Note that this works for `std::string` because it has an overloaded `operator==`**

Answer (score 2):

getGrade() return string then you need Courses[i].getGrade().c_str()

Answer (score 1):

use `Courses[i].getGrade().c_str()`this returns `char*` (`const char*`) of string buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
if(strncmp(Courses[i].getGrade().c_str(), "A") == 0)
```

Comment: You're using the `strcmp` signature - `strncmp` expects a third argument that specifies how many characters to limit the comparison to.

Answer (score 0):

I would just rewrite your `getGrage()` function to be

```
 float getGrade(){ 
     float grade = 1 + 'D' - toupper(grade[0]); 
     if (grade < 1 || grade > 4) 
         return 0;
     if (grade[1] == '+') return grade + 0.3;
     if (grade[1] == '-') return grade - 0.3;
     return grade;
 };
```